# JavaScript or JQuery Take right selected value from select options from multiple select tables generated thro for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, dom-events

I've tried to get solutions from Google and earlier asked questions but questions and answers relate to only one select having multiple options.  To clarify more, when I generate code  for loop to create multiple select on screen and then use JavaScript to get `selectedIndex` or value and use alert to check if correct value is taken, then only value from selected option from first select table generated through for loop is shown repeated. Kindly find the code below:

---

```
<body>
  <script>

    // JSON code getting g named array throgh JSON.parse method
    for (g=0; g<m.length; g++) {
      n += "  <select id=\"mySelect\" onchange=\"myFunction()\">";
      n += "    <option> - Select Option - </option>";
      n += "<option>A</option>";
      n += "    <option>B</option>";
      n += "    <option>C</option>";
      n += "    <option>D</option>";
      n += "  </select>";
    } // end of for loop
  
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;   

    // in between some code

    function myFunction() {
      var y = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      var j = y.selectedIndex;
      var b = y.options[j].text;
      alert ("Your answer is: " + b);
    } // end of myFunction
  </script>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

When execute this code, e.g. `if (arrayG.length is 5)`, then select-option is shown on screen five times, is perfect, when we select option from first select-options loop alert shows perfect selected option. e.g. If we select C from first select then alert shows C, but when we select options from other four select elements it still shows C i.e. selected option from first select elements.

We want our code to show right selected options from different 5 select elements generated through above for loop.

Request to kindly help, since we have mined a lot for the answer.

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: _“request to kindly help, since we have mined a lot for the answer.”_ - suggest you go “mine” for some basics first, and work through some beginner’s tutorial or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments,  yes I'm beginner. May we request the tutorial where can find solution to exactly this problem.  I've tried with unique id and value within for loop.

Comment: Tried "+i+" in value to get unique value in function as well as in html document but still desired results not achived

Comment: `onchange="foo(this)"`, `function foo(element) { ... }` #LookMaNoIds

Comment: Tried onchange event but still when all select tables appear on screen number of times  based on number of rows of database,  when we can be the option of any select table only first select table's value / text is shown. Request if any member can help with the code

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are trying to say here. Could help if you created a proper, executable [mcve] first, so that we can see what you are talking about. Do you want the output of all those select fields show up in that one `#demo` element (so that each new selection replaces the previous one), or something else?

Comment: Apology. I had by mistake mentioned 'g' as array. It's 'm' array got from database through Ajax json parse and data is stored in it. The result I want to achieve through code is suppose there are three rows from database with correct option as C, A, D for row number 1, 2, 3 respectively of multidimensional  array got from database. Now, user of course is not aware of correct options of 1, 2, and 3rd row. Now, the above mentioned code is generating Three HTML 'select' tables (ie equal to rows from database), each with 4 options A, B, C, D. Now, user has to select one option (out of four options

Comment: @GuruprasadT please review my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. Thank you so much damanptyltd

Answer (score 0):

As Cbroe heavily hinted, you need to pass the select element to the method with 'this', then use that reference to find the selected value.

```
var m = 3;
var n = "";
// JSON code getting g named array throgh JSON.parse method
for(g=0; g<m; g++) {
  n += "  <select id=\"mySelect" 
  n += g;
  n += "\" onchange=\"myFunction(this)\">";
  n += "    <option> - Select Option - </option>";
  n += "<option>A</option>";
  n += "    <option>B</option>";
  n += "    <option>C</option>";
  n += "    <option>D</option>";
  n += "  </select>";
} // end of for loop

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;   

// in between some code

function myFunction(element) {
  var j = e.selectedIndex;
  var b = e.options[j].text;
  alert ("Your answer is: " + b);
} // end of myFunction
```

[jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/cicavatotu/edit?html,console,output)

Or you could pass the index and find it with the id that way.

```
var m = 3;
var n = "";

// JSON code getting g named array throgh JSON.parse method
for(g=0; g<m; g++) {
  n += "  <select id=\"mySelect" 
  n += g;
  n += "\" onchange=\"myFunction(";
  n += g;
  n += ")\">";
  n += "    <option> - Select Option - </option>";
  n += "<option>A</option>";
  n += "    <option>B</option>";
  n += "    <option>C</option>";
  n += "    <option>D</option>";
  n += "  </select>";
} // end of for loop

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;   

// in between some code

function myFunction(index) {
  var y = document.getElementById("mySelect" + index);
  var j = y.selectedIndex;
  var b = y.options[j].text;
  alert ("Your answer is: " + b);
} // end of myFunction
```

[jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/takunabima/edit?html,console,output)

It is very clear by your code/question structure that you are not equipped to handle javascript basics. You will need to do some introduction javascript courses otherwise you will continue to struggle a lot, and make a lot of bad code.